# yii2+nginx, subdomain to module

Tags: php, nginx, yii2

I have a project working on yii2 (backend nginx). The project has several modules, it can be conditionally called:

- Category 1 (cat1)
- Category 2 (cat2)

It is required to implement the functionality so that when requesting `cat1.coolsite.example`, it opens a module that is available as `coolsite.example/cat1`. Accordingly, the second category

Answer (score 1):

Try adding 2 server configs for your modules like this one and look at nginx error.log if it doesn't do the trick.

```
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name cat1.coolsite.example,;

    location / {
            proxy_pass coolsite.example/cat1/$uri;
    }
}
```